# Como utilizo o progress bar

Tags: android, gps, progress-bar

Eu tenho um aplicação android,  que trás a latitude e longitude .
eu queria que no momento  que ele tá requisitando ele colocasse um progress bar pra dá um feedback .

segue o código da localização

```
 private void start(){
         locationManager = (LocationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, locationListener);
 }

 private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
            String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();

        txtTextos =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdate);


            txtTextos.setText(txtTextos.getText().toString() + "\n Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude() + "\n Latitude : " + loc.getLatitude());


        }
```

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo, qual a linguagem que você está utilizando, e java?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Comment: Sim, e pra android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quando você precisa fazer algumas tarefas que precisam de carregamento como operações de rede ou algo que pode aparentar que sua aplicação está travada, deve-se usar uma thread separada para isso. Porém essa essa outra thread não pode atualizar a interface gráfica, ou seja, ela não deve alterar o conteúdo de qualquer componente visual. Para contornar esse problema, existe a classe AsyncTask, que nos permite implementar o código que será executado antes, durante e depois da execução de alguma tarefa realizada em background, você pode colocar essa classe dentro da sua activity. Segue código

```
 import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class testeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste);

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    private void exibirProgress(boolean exibir) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(exibir ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

    class MinhaTask extends AsyncTask<Location,Void,Location> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            exibirProgress(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Location doInBackground(Location... params) {
            return medotodoRetornaLocation();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Location location) {
            super.onPostExecute(location);
            exibirProgress(false);
            metodoAtualizaAInterfaceGrafica(location);
        }
    }
}
```

O método exibir exibirProgress(boolean); é o método responsável em exibir ou não o progress na view.

Declaração do progress na view:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        />
```

Agora adicione os métodos que atualizam a interface gráfica e o que vai buscar a localização e seja feliz! \o/

Para saber mais da classe AsyncTask segue link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html